# Swagger Giving 404 Error in Java while calling Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am fairly new to Java and I am Getting 404 in Java in Swagger as shown Below. The Screenshot is attached Below. Please comment if you require anything else. I added a swaggerConfig.java file where I posted the Below Code. Basically I need to operate a Swagger UI to test my APIs. Please help me regarding this

[Click for Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4hpz.png)

Below is the SwaggerConfig.java

```
package com.jsqwerty.be.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("API")
                .description("Service API")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("http://springfox.io")
                .contact(new Contact("springfox", "", ""))
                .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/LICENSE")
                .version("2.0")
                .build();
    }

}
```

Below is the Code for pom.xml

```
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.jsqwerty</groupId>
   <artifactId>be</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>be</name>
   <description>Learning Platform</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
         <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
         <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
         <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
         <version>2.9.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax</groupId>
         <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
         <version>7.0</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

I am using url -> http://localhost:8080/be/swagger-ui.html

Comment: Can you please share the application.properties file or yml file? Also make sure you have added @EnableSwagger...annotation on main class.

Comment: ```spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blook
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Green@pp1e
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Comment: `package com.jsqwerty.be;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class BeApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(BeApplication.class, args);
 }

}
`

Comment: Above is my BeApplication.java class

Comment: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html try this endpoint

Comment: Getting

Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually: